# Inserting and updating records from 3 tables in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am storing records for my product transfer app using 3 tables in single action. Transferhistories, Warehouse1StockSummaries and Warehouse2StockSummaries.

storing records to trasnferinghistories is ok, and also the increment method I declare to Warehouse2StockSummaries is also working fine except for Warehouse1StockSummaries.

here's my store function,

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $items = [];

    for($i=0; $i<= count($input['product_id']); $i++) {

        // if(empty($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]) || !is_numeric($input['stock_in_qty'][$i])) continue;
        if(!isset($input['qty_in'][$i]) || !is_numeric($input['qty_in'][$i])) continue;

        $acceptItem = [
            'product_id'    => $input['product_id'][$i],
            'transfer_qty'  => $input['qty_out'][$i],
            'user_id'       => $input['user_id'][$i]
        ];       
        array_push($items, Transferhistories::create($acceptItem));

        // dd($input);

        //update warehouse 1 summary
        $warehouse1summary = Warehouse1StockSummaries::firstOrCreate(
            ['product_id' => $input['product_id'][$i]],
            ['qty_in' => $input['qty_in'][$i],
             'qty_out' => $input['qty_out'][$i]
        ]);

        if (!$warehouse1summary->wasRecentlyCreated) {
            $warehouse1summary->increment('qty_out', $input['qty_out'][$i]);
        }


        //update warehouse 2 summary
        $stock2Summary = Warehouse2StockSummaries::firstOrCreate(
            ['product_id' => $input['product_id'][$i]], 
            ['qty_in' => $input['qty_out'][$i],'qty_out' => null]);

        if (!$stock2Summary->wasRecentlyCreated) {
            $stock2Summary->increment('qty_in', $input['qty_in'][$i]);
        } 

    }
    return redirect()->route('transferHistory.index');
}
```

updating warehouse 1 summary is not doing what it should be.

any suggestion master? thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I think I am having an issue with "firstOrCreate" in update warehouse 1 summary,  because when I change it to "updateOrFirst" I see changes in database but what I need in this process is the "firstOrCreate" any suggestion guys? thanks

Comment: You are trying to update the `product_id` and the `qty_out`? Or you are trying to update the `qty_out` from the record with `product_id`? What is the problem? Is not saving?It throw a error?

Comment: I am trying to update the qty_out from the record with product_id for warehouse1summary. the weird part is, the qty_in is updating. If i run dd($warehouse1summary); I can see that the suppose value for qty_out is there, if I ran save qty_out is blank but qty_in is updated. I am referring to $warehouse1summary. there is no error showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to laravel, `firstOrCreate` does not save the value, so after you do:

```
$warehouse1summary = Warehouse1StockSummaries::updateOrCreate(
            ['product_id' => $input['product_id'][$i]],
            ['qty_in' => $input['qty_in'][$i],
             'qty_out' => $input['qty_out'][$i]
        ]);
```

**Edit**

The method `firstOrNew` will return the first or a instance of the `Model`.
So what you wanna do is this:

```
$warehouse1summary = Warehouse1StockSummaries::firstOrNew(
    ['product_id' => $input['product_id'][$i]],
    ['qty_in' => $input['qty_in'][$i],
    'qty_out' => $input['qty_out'][$i]
]);
if(isset($warehouse1summary->created_at)){
    $warehouse1summary->qty_out = $warehouse1summary->qty_out + $input['qty_out'][$i];
}
$warehouse1summary->save();
```

Comment: hi @AlbertoGuilherme still doesn't save the qty_out for $warehouse1summary. :(

Comment: @Lito - I change the answer so it use the method `updateOrCreate`. Could you test it?

Comment: yes this one works I actually tried it earlier my problem with updateOrCreate my condition doesn't fit to my need. I need the qty_out value to add to its previous record. the condition I set works with firstOrCreate. in updateOrCreate in the other hand, what happen is it just override the previous record with incremented value of qty_out

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding what is the problem and what are you trying to do. If there is no record on the database, you wanna save the `id` and `qty_out`, and if there is a record, you wanna increase on the same `id` another `qty_out`??

Comment: yes. because the scenario is, all the products from $warehouse1summary are came from purchase orders. when the user received the deliveries the summarized value of the product are storing there. Now i am in the part where I need to transfer some stocks(products) to $warehouse2summary, so let say I will transfer 200 bottles. I'd say, if the bottle is already in the record, keep the qty_in and add the 200 in the QTY_out so every time the user transfer a product qty_out keeps on adding. yes your conclusion is correct.

Comment: @Lito - Now it should solve your problem. Let me know if it does.

Comment: Hi @AlbertoGuilherme it actually does, but only if the qty_out has a previous record. Same as firstOrCreate. they doesn't work on empty qty_out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190320/discussion-between-alberto-guilherme-and-lito).

Comment: so I guess is the best approach is to make another condition to check if the qty_out is empty, if it is use updateOrCreate or firstOrCreate when otherwise?